# How to expose individual form elements from user-register-form

Tags: forms, users

So I have a work flow/use case as such:

- an administrator user creates a user account, associating it to the "guest" role
- the guest users receive a login link
- once they log in, I want them to provide some information (in this case, rsvp status, a custom field I've added to the user profile)

Is it possible to display just the rsvp form field of the registration form, so they can update it when they log in (e.g., they submit one field only and the profile is updated)?

Is there another way to do this? I'd rather do this in code since it's part of a custom module that is nearly completed.

Comment: Well, using the Form API, I just built a form that has a checkbox. The submit function does a db UPDATE of the appropriate field... While the query is succesful (I can confirm in PHPmyadmin that the value changes from 0 to 1) the field remains unchanged in the UI when the User views their profile... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your doing your own module hook_form_alter is the way to go. so long as all required fields are already supplied you should be able to set all other fields to have type hidden.

If you are looking to do something similar you may want to look at the event and rspv modules.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use [Profile Setup](http://drupal.org/project/profile_setup) and [Pageroute](http://drupal.org/project/pageroute), and [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to guide people through the process of providing your basic information when first logging in.